# How to set human readable URL for detail page in Typo3 v8 News System

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I just start to work a project from client which uses Typo3 v8.7.19, News System & Real URl. Currently, it already has a Projects, an overview and a detail page for Projects, which have readable url:

> **Overview**: mysite.com/projects/ 
> **Detail**: mysite.com/projects/project-detail/news/project-1 
> *(don't know why is has a /news/ before post's url, but that's still readable for now)*.

Now I have to add another called Events, so I added a folder called Events, then created a page for overview and a single detail page. Every pages load correctly with correct data, but this is the URL that I have for detail page:

> mysite.com/events/event-detail/?L=0&tx_news_pi1%5Bnews%5D=79&cHash=0f4fee77e25133ebe9f437100f0dd1f2

I thought it should be like this:

> **Overview**: mysite.com/events/ 
> **Detail**: mysite.com/events/event-detail/news/event-1

Can someone explain to me what is wrong here and how can I change it to readable URL? For more information, I don't have the access to the server so I didn't code or add any code in the extension source. And I'm using Typo3 8.7.19, Real URL 2.4.0, News System 7.0.5.

Sorry for the long explanation, I'm new to Typo3.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tsure which version from ext:news your are at, but try to read the News documentation on RealURL here: https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/8.3/en-us/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Realurl/Index.html

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'm using Real URL 2.4.0 and News System 7.0.5.

Comment: And did the docs help you ? Will need some more input to be able to help

Comment: Yes, it helped, sorry for my late response, it worked.

Comment: No worries. Glad to hear and to be able to help.